# How to send Pako.js deflated data (Uint8Array) to React-Native Kotlin Bridge file?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, kotlin, pako

not able to send Pako deflated (Uint8Array) data to react-native Kotlin native module

in React native File

```
let msg = JSON.stringify(largeDate);
let compressed = pako.deflate(msg);
```

send the Compressed data Through Amazone chime react native bridge file

`NativeFunction.sendDataMessage(type, compressed, 1000);`

Inside Kotlin File

```
    fun sendDataMessage(topic: String, message: ByteArray, lifetimeMs: Int) {
        meetingSession?.audioVideo?.realtimeSendDataMessage(topic, message, lifetimeMs)
    }
```

```
 "pako": "^2.1.0",
 "react": "^18.2.0",
 "react-native": "^0.71.11"
```